# AngularJS with RESTful MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, angularjs, rest

I use AngularJS with RESTful WebService using MySQL database. I get data from database to view page. But my problem is: I can't sum in function.

Problem Code:

```
$scope.currentAssetsSum = function () {

//return parseFloat($scope.currentAssetsData.cash_hand) + parseFloat($scope.currentAssetsData.bank_account);

return $scope.currentAssetsData['cash_hand'] + $scope.currentAssetsData['bank_account'];

};
```

---

[JAR List:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxfnU.png)

---

MySQL Database:

```
    CREATE TABLE  current_assets (
id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
cash_hand double NOT NULL, 
bank_account double NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY  (id));
```

NetBeans Web Application Project:

https://github.com/hellodewdrop/AngularJS_RESTful_MySQL

Comment: You need to make sure your function return an int or float when summing them.

Comment: @HRgiger: there is no need to add bold to all the technologies in use - that makes it harder to read. Just make sure the OP has got the case right (e.g. MySQL rather than MYSQL).

Comment: @halfer noted:)

Comment: Pls check source code: https://github.com/hellodewdrop/AngularJS_RESTful_MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare the variable $scope.currentAssetsData as an object before? And then you can make the conversion, if your data is not a float.

Something like:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
           $scope.currentAssetsData = {};

            //Current Assets Table
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:8084/Final_Balance/rest/currentAssets"
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.currentAssetsData = response.data;
                console.log($scope.currentAssetsData.length);
            }, function myError(response) {
                console.log("Data can't be loaded..");
            });
            //Calculation from Table
            $scope.currentAssetsSum = function () {
                return parseFloat($scope.currentAssetsData.cash_hand) + parseFloat($scope.currentAssetsData.bank_account);
            };
        });
```

Comment: I have update my answer according to your code. Try to substitute this controller code that is in index.html to the edited mine, and see if it works!

Comment: Which result was returning before?

Comment: I want return sum of two field value that was get from database. It works properly: {{item.bank_account + item.cash_hand}}. But did not sum in function.
Brother, in github my netbeans project. Pls run it then you got the problem.

Comment: I downloaded the project and when I press F12 on chrome, it says: "Cannot read property 'cash_hand' of undefined", which means your  $scope.currentAssetsData is not declared. If in that code that I passed to you result is NaN, probably means that your API is not returning the correct data, or is not returning data.